# Вызов WEB API сервисов в контроллерах ASP.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, веб-служба

Нужен хороший пример использования WEB API сервисов на back-end ASP.net mvc. Много вопросов возникает при вызове сервисов в контроллерах. Нужно писать обертку для каждого сервиса WEB API? например, сервис

```
GET api/User/GetUserLogin?Username={Username}&Pwd={Pwd}&ClientID=ClientID}&DivisionID={DivisionID}
```

И обертка для него:

```
public User Login(string name, string password, int divisionId)
    {
        using (var client =  new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ProjectConfiguration.ServiceUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var url = string.Format("User/GetUserLogin?Username={0}&Pwd={1}&ClientID={2}&DivisionID={3}",name, password, ProjectConfiguration.ClientId, divisionId);
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) : new User();
        }
    }
```

Еще вопрос: как обрабатывать в контроллерах ошибки HTTP?
Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Вопрос достаточно сложный для конкретного ответа. Попробуй немного конкретизировать проблему. А вообще в подобных ситуация нужно выносить отдельный слой оберток над API и работать уже непосредственно с ними. Я могу попробовать привести пример, когда локализуешь проблему.

Comment: Павел, можете приказать пример вашей обертки и ее использования в контроллере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал набросать пример, думаю, общий подход из него будет ясен.
Слоев абстракции должно быть несколько, и продумайте принципы сериализации моделей и механизм построения URL.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISingInTask _singInTask;

    public TestController()
    {
        _singInTask = new SingInTask();
    }

    [ValidateModel]
    [HandleAllExceptions]
    public ActionResult SignIn(SignInModel model)
    {
        _singInTask.SignIn(model.UserName, model.Password);
    }
}

public class SingInTask : BaseRestWrapper, ISingInTask
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, string password)
    {
        var uri = UriHelper.CreateUri("api/signin");
        var result = base.Post<SignInRestServiseResponseModel>(
            uri,
            new { userName, password },
            null);

        if (result != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ErrorMessage))
        {
            return;
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRestWrapper : ApiClient
{
    public BaseRestWrapper()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"].TrimEnd('/'))
        };
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Uri uri, object model, object uriModel)
    {
        var requestUri = uri;

        if (uriModel != null)
        {
            requestUri = AddModelToUri(uri, uriModel);
        }

        var responce = Client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri.ToString(), model).Result;
        return responce;
    }

    private static Uri AddModelToUri(Uri uri, object model)
    {
        var prms = model
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(item => new { item.Name, Value = item.GetValue(model) })
            .Where(item => item.Value != null)
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Name, item => item.Value.ToString());

        var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);

        foreach (var prm in prms)
        {
            builder.SetQueryParam(prm.Key, prm.Value);
        }

        return builder.Uri;
    }
}
```